# PL/SQL: Receiving an array as a parameter and looping through it

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to process an array of string values (single column) called from C++ code, and iterate over it using PL/SQL in a stored procedure.
For that I have created a new type:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE "DEVICELIST_OBJTYP" AS OBJECT
 (DEVICE VARCHAR2(46 BYTE))
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE devicelist_coltyp AS
    TABLE OF devicelist_objtyp;
/
```

The PL/SQL procedure looks as follows (with seemingly irrelevant logic removed):

```
PROCEDURE pr_MyProc
    ( p_UserId              IN     USERSTAB.USRID%TYPE,
    p_DeviceList            IN     DEVICELIST_OBJTYP,
    p_ResCode               OUT    NUMBER,
    p_ResMsg                OUT    VARCHAR2)
IS
BEGIN
...
FOR i IN 1 .. p_DeviceList.COUNT LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line(i);
    --more code to follow..
END LOOP;
...
END;
/
```

When I try to compile the procedure, I fail with:

```
Warning: Package Body created with compilation errors.

Errors for PACKAGE BODY PA_HANDLE_ASSETS:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
135/17   PL/SQL: Statement ignored
135/44   PLS-00302: component 'COUNT' must be declared
BEGIN
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20002:
ORA-06512: at line 4
```

How should I iterate over the nested table object without providing the .COUNT attribute? When I tried without the .COUNT, I errored out with something in the line of ~"p_DeviceList is not a cursor".
Should I convert the p_DeviceList object to another type of data?

Comment: Should the type of the parameter be `devicelist_coltyp`?

Comment: @BobJarvis-ReinstateMonica, you are correct! Thank you!!